# Check if a process is running using PHP in Linux

Tags: php, linux, daemon, kannel

I am using *kannel* to send SMS via PHP. I want to know how can I check if a particular process is running. For *kannel* to run, a process named `bearerbox` should be running all time. I want to check if this process is running or not. Because if the process is not running then a mail will be sent to me notifying me about it.

Comment: you could use a php exec function

Comment: Make sure it's not possible for external users to modify your exec() calls, hardcode them if possible. Bad code can give evil minded people access to the whole system.

Comment: @mattis , yeah sure I will keep that in Mind. @ldg thanks for suggestion buddy, thats exactly what I will be using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if process still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111406/checking-if-process-still-running)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest is to use `pgrep`, which has an exit code of 0 if the process exists, 1 otherwise.

Here's an example.

```
exec("pgrep bearerbox", $output, $return);
if ($return == 0) {
    echo "Ok, process is running\n";
}
```

Comment: You may want to check, but from what I found the exit codes are the opposite way around- 1 if it exists; 0 if not. Can anyone clarify on this?

Comment: @MattFletcher: pgrep fails (rc=1) if no process is found with that name (just tried it out).

Comment: Through shell, yes, but I just tried it out in PHP CLI and it does it the opposite way around. `$output` will return an array, empty or with each PID. Echoing the `exec()` command will return the PID or null. `$return` returned 0 if the process doesn't exist and 1 if it does!

Comment: Ps: This is using PHP 5.4.9 on Ubuntu 13

Comment: Update: I think maybe just the timing on the commands I was running was a bit glitchy, my bad... It is the original way around described. Thought it was weird because I've seen the whole "exit code is 0 if it exists" thing in C before :)

Comment: @MattFletcher: that's odd. I'm getting `$return == 0` for existing processes, 1 otherwise (PHP 5.4.8 on RedHat).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the exec command to find your process and then act accordingly.

Something like:

`exec('ps aux | grep bearerbox', $output);`

You'll need to work out what is returned on your server to decide if it's running or not.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to deal with this. The easiest (and a direct answer to your question) is to grab the output of 'ps'.

Deamons tend to always create a 'pid' file though. This file contains the process-id of the daemon. If yours has that, you can check the contents of the file and see if the process with that id is still running. This is more reliable.

[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) might also have this functionality. Lastly, maybe it's better to get a real monitoring system rather than build something yourself. Nagios might be a good pick, but there might be others.

Answer (score 3):

Simple yet handy solution to monitor processes through PHP: [PHP-Linux-Process-Monitor](https://github.com/Samer-Al-iraqi/PHP-Linux-Process-Monitor).

The code goals like:

```
$ps = explode("\n", trim(shell_exec('ps axo pid,ppid,%cpu,pmem,user,group,args --sort %cpu')));
foreach($ps AS $process){
$processes[]=preg_split('@\s+@', trim($process), 7 );
}
$head= array_shift($processes);
$processes = array_reverse($processes);
$output='';
foreach ($head AS $f) $output.="<td class=\"head\">$f</td>";
$output=sprintf('<tr class="head">%s</tr>',$output);
foreach($processes AS $p){
    $output.='<tr>';
    foreach ($p AS $i=>$f){
        if($i==0) $output.=sprintf('<td>%1$s</td>',$f);
        elseif($i==2) $output.=sprintf('<td class="cpu">%1$s<ins style="width:%1$s%%"></ins></td>',$f);
        elseif($i==3) $output.=sprintf('<td class="mem">%1$s<ins style="width="%1$s%%"></ins></td>',$f);
        elseif($i == 6) $output.=sprintf('<td class="command">%1$s</td>',$f);
        else $output.=sprintf('<td>%1$s</td>',$f);
    }
    $output.='</tr>';
}
$cpu=implode('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', sys_getloadavg());
$output=sprintf('<table data-cpu="%s" id="process">%s</table>',$cpu, $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way

```
<?php
exec("ps -eo comm,pid | awk '$1 == "."\"gs\""." { print $2 }'", $output);
if ($output != 0) {
    echo "The process gs is running\n";
}
?>
```

in the above code gs is the process that I was checking