# Check if a script is runing with PHP

Tags: php

I have TeamSpeak3 installed don my server and I want to make a small script that shows if TS3 is up or down

**Configuration** :

CentOS 7
Php 5.6.24

I tried this script but didn't work for me :

```
exec("pgrep ts3server", $pids);
if(empty($pids)) {

    echo "ts3server is not running!";
}
```

when I echo the $pids I get nothing it's empty, and when I run the command "pgrep ts3server" I get this result : 11149.

**Added Info:**

Yes I have root access, and I think that exec isn't installed because I don't get any results from this :

```
<?php
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}

echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

I tried to enable but can't find nothing about in php.ini!

Comment: privillegies problem ?

Comment: It's a privileges problem. You might want to try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29716674/3885509

Comment: tried that code in ur link and didn't work it gave NULL

Comment: Guessing but what is your SELinux status and loaded policy? Check SELinux by running `sestatus` from the console. You may need to disable SELinux or configure it for your environment.

Comment: Even by disabling SeLinux still don't work

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the 'ts3server' is the name of the process for teamspeak?

Try the snippet below.

```
$var = exec('pgrep ts3server', $pids);
var_dump($pids, $var);
```

If that doesn't work maybe remove the pgrep part.

```
$var = exec('ts3server', $pids);
var_dump($pids, $var);
```

If that doesn't work it might be that the exec() command is disabled, you could try using backticks.

```
$var = `pgrep ts3server`;
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Why back-ticks for the string?

Comment: backticks is an execution operator in php. [Execution Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: Ah, did not know that.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the 3 of them are giving NULL and when using the   pgrep ts3server command I get the id

Comment: As some people have stated it could be a permission issue.  Is this on a machine you have full access to (root privileges)?

Comment: Edited my post and Added info

Comment: Hmm, open up your php.ini file and look for a line with "disable_functions" if the exec or shell_exec commands are listed then, copy and paste the same line underneath, comment out the original and then remove the two functions I mentioned and save the ini file and try again.

Comment: yeah I checked for this too, disable_functions = is empty

Comment: Are you running the script from a web interface or from the CLI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120334/discussion-between-dolomats-and-sunil).