# Check if a Python job is running using PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I've got a python script thats called twice a day via a CRON job to trigger an alarm that runs in a loop, and is terminated by pressing a physical button and calling a destroy function when that button is pressed.

So far so good.

Now, I'd like to check via PHP if that script is running - so before the button is pressed but after it's called via CRON.

How can I do this?

[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111406/checking-if-process-still-running) - I've tried the following:

```
exec("jobs", $pids);
if(!empty($pids)) {
    print_r($pids);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be returning any value. Calling `jobs` from the terminal works as expected and lists the job as running when invoking the script directly using `python3 alarm.py &`.

Using `exec("ps -A | grep -i $processName | grep -v grep", $pids);` I feel won't work since the process ID can change and can not be known until the script is running.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pgrep` for this:

```
pgrep -f 'python scriptname.py ...'
```

`-f` can be used specify the full command line of the python process to avoid collision with multiple python processes running in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! When I call this using PHP's exec function I don't get any result. Pasting `pgrep -f python /home/pi/Projects/sound.py` directly into the terminal I get the following error: "pgrep: only one pattern can be provided".

Typing in `pgrep -f python` in the terminal correctly returns the PID of the script, but since the PID is unknown until the script is run I'm at a bit of a loss...

Comment: You need to quote the path. Sorry. updated my answer